# mask phone number, show full phone number on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a little application that displays a bunch of phone numbers.

The javascript object looks something like this:

```
myObject.phoneNumber = model.phoneNumber;
```

Then i display myObject.phoneNumber on the screen. However, I'd like to mask it so look something like XXX-XXX-1234. Then, whenever you mouse over the phone number, you see the whole phone number!

I was thinking of doing something like this...

```
myObject.phoneNumber = model.phoneNumber;
myObject.maskedNumber = model.phoneNumber.replaceFirst6WithX's //psuedoCode
```

Then on mouse over,

```
    $(".phoneNumber")
        .mouseOver(function (e) {
            $(".phoneNumber").hide();
            $(".maskedNumber").show()
        });
```

and on mouse out do the opposite.

So my question is: how do i mask (or hide the first 6) numbers of the phone number to accomplish this?

Comment: Does it need to be secure? ie is it ok if someone can read the full phone number from the HTML source?

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be secure. The phone numbers can be read in the source. This is simply to cut down on confusion, not to hide any sensitive information from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplistic example, yet functional.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WacQR/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var phone = "1234567890";
phone.replace(phone.substring(0,6), 'XXXXXX');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myObject.maskedNumber = "XXX-XXX" + myObject.phoneNumber.substring(7);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a function to return the string with the first 6 digits/chars as "x":

```
function mark(phone) {
    var str='';
    var count=0;
    for(i=0; i<phone.length; i++) {
        if(phone.charAt(i)!="-" && count<6) {
            str+='x';
            count++;
        }
        else
            str+=phone.charAt(i);
    }
    return str;
}
```

You can change the content of the element to the returned string when mouse is over it. This accounts for the "-" in the number. You can also change it to detect anything that is not a digit.